# Calculating Core-Level Binding Energies (XPS) using DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, spectroscopy, excited-states

I'm pretty new to DFT calculations but I'm trying to learn how to do [X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy) (XPS) calculations, particularly for open-shell molecular systems in common non-periodic DFT codes.

Comment: You may have a look at my answer here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/recommended-code-to-do-xas-xes-rixs-calculations-with/8549#8549. However this answer only covers molecular codes, and I'm eager to see if anyone can comment on how to do these type of calculations with periodic codes.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community Ademola, and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future. Thank you @Tristan for making improvements.

Comment: @wzkchem5 since your answer addresses the molecular part, do you think it would make sense to mark this question as a duplicate and extend the prior question to also specifically ask how this can be done for periodic code? That would collect all the answers in one place

Comment: @Tyberius would that discourage people from answering the earlier question, given that it already had an answer (although it was only a partial one)? I would assume that a question with no existing answer has a higher chance of being answered

Comment: @wzkchem5 Your answer covers XAS not XPS.  Maybe a shorter answer for a molecular calculation of XPS is appropriate here (given changes at the DFT/post processing level). I think this is a similar question to the "duplicate" but this question does address XPS not XAS (although we can argue they are similar in nature, I think).

Comment: @TristanMaxson Ah yes I overlooked that... Then the present question is surely not duplicate.

Comment: @wzkchem5 would it be hard to answer this question for the case of XPS? I was nervous about removing the part about periodic codes earlier as it was endorsed by Tristan, but upon reflection ~6.5 months later, I think it's better for this question to be about non-periodic codes (which you can probably answer), and to have a separate question asking whether or not any periodic codes can do this type of calculation. This is why we discourage two questions in the same post: if someone can answer about non-periodic and not the periodic part, then the question goes 6.5 months without an answer.